# WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 Admin Portal not accessible

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to access the admin portal of wso2 by using newly created user("subuser") and role("subadmin") by following [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-users-for-admin-portal/).

Meanwhile, I am facing some other issue, Unfortunately can't able to access the same wso2 admin portal by using "admin" credentials. but the same can be accessible before some time(30 mins back)

I haven't change any config file. while login, the management console shows errors like below.

[image: Forbidden ERROR]

**Note**: Nothing ERROR is shown in the Log file. I tried to restart server, system everything, unfortunately, this won't help me.

Comment: DId you mistakenly change the permissions of the admin user?

Comment: Hi @rnavagamuwa,
I haven't change any permission for admin user and admin role in carbon portal. I hope Permission of admin role can't able to modify. I have compared deployment.toml file config with fresh package, nothing changed related to admin. I can able to login in the carbon portal, problem only with admin portal

Comment: If you are using a custom role with admin permissions make sure that you have done the role mapping in the admin portal. You need to add the relevant scopes to the custom role, else, you will not be able to login to the admin portal.  The custom admin role should have at least the following scopes to log into the admin portal. The relevant scopes are apim:api_workflow_view, apim:api_workflow_approve, apim:admin_settings and apim:tenantInfo.

Comment: Hi @ Saranki Magenthirarajah,
Thank you for your information. Even though my scenario is to use custom role, custom user to login, i am not able to login into admin portal by using default "admin" credentials. once login in the admin portal, then only i can able to do role mapping. right? PS: I have deleted custom role and the user in carbon portal now. Still admin portal is not accessible by using admin credentials.

Comment: Hi @SarankiMagenthirarajah
wso2 admin portal login issue resolved by following Athiththan answer mentioned below, After this i tried to create custom role,custom user and role mapping was done as per your suggestion, Now i can able to sign in into the admin portal with custom user. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspect that the relevant Role Mapping configurations are not updated properly in the API Manager server and causing this behavior.

I assume that you are using API Manager 3.2.0 GA in your environment and you have created a custom role and made the Role Mappings from the Admin portal. Can you perform the following configuration check and update the missing entries

- Login to the Carbon Management console (/carbon) using the super admin credentials
- In the Left Pane, under `Resources` click `Browse`
- Go to `_system` > `config` > `apimgt` > `applicationdata` and select the `tenant-conf.json`
- Select `Edit as text` on the next page and search for the JSON Key named: `RoleMappings`. If you have performed a Role Mapping from the Admin portal for your custom role, a mapping should be there as following

  ```json
  "RoleMappings": {
     "admin": "custom-role"
  }
  ```
- Update the mapping including the `admin` in the value as following

  ```json
  "RoleMappings": {
     "admin": "admin,custom-role"
  }
  ```
- Once the changes are appended, Save the content and restart the API Manager to clear the caches and load the configurations properly

Once restarted, try logging into the Admin portal and share the observations.
A similar issue has been identified and reported under [#product-apim/issues/9461](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9461)

Comment: Hi @Athiththan,
A big thank you for posting exact solution for my issue. I have changed like below."RoleMappings": {
   "admin": "admin"
}, previously it looks like "RoleMappings": {
   "admin": "subadmin"
}